# python matplotlib illegal instruction

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm experiencing a strange crash when
I try to plot in python using matplotlib

For example, running the following command in the python interpreter

```
>>> import matplotlib.pylab
>>> pylab.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

produces the error

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.
My python packages have the following versions:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'

>>> numpy.__version__
'1.6.1'

>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.1.1rc'

>>> matplotlib.pylab.__version__
'1.6.1'
```

I would appreciate greatly any ideas on what might cause my problem.

Comment: Read the core dump - I had a similar problem on Debian unstable about a year ago. It was related to a qt library problem, which was upgraded. Also trying different matplotlib-backend might also put some light in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to change the BLAS libraries.

try (you need to use sudo here):

`update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3`

and select a different library. I found the the "atlas-base" libraries to work. (on a Debian Wheezy, python3, I installed the altlas3-base libraries and it works ok)

I also installed the package "fort77" which seems a requirement [here](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/)